# Removing execute permissions on `/tmp` or mounting it with `noexec` flag?

Tags: hardening, permissions, code-execution

The CIS security benchmark recommends mounting `/tmp` and all other world writable directories on a separate partition so it could be mounted with the `noexec` flag.

Since I already have my `/tmp` mounted in the same partition as `/` and I would prefer to avoid the hustle of repartitioning, I would like to know what's the difference (in security terms - meaning, the risks) between `chmod -R -x /tmp` and mounting a separate partition with the `noexec` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually discussing three separate hardening techniques.

**Separate Partitions**

Separate partitions does two things for you. It first isolates systems. This can be beneficial in many ways not just security such as for storage concerns. From the security standpoint, you isolate those directories which a globally accessed, and can easily remove, rebuild, and redeploy without the work of you boot partition needing a full rebuild.

Second, backups. It not uncommon to run backup systems across a partition home dir and use a config management tool such as Chef or Puppet on the root system. Roots system configs rarely change, and in a full rebuild situation, it usually becomes more beneficial to deploy "/" files based on Chef or Puppet to maintain standards, than recover users files, other than restoring config files from backup.

**Mounting**

It's been a while, and I don't have my Nix system in front of me, but should should be able to go into the fstab file and edit the /tmp directory to use the NOEXEC flag. This should not require a separate partition. The flag from the MAN PAGES:

> **noexec**
>
> Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted
>   filesystem. (Until recently it was possible to run binaries anyway
>   using a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary. This trick fails since
>   Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)

It does what it says.

**CHMOD**

Change Mode is used to change permission at the File/Directory level. If you read the man page for chmod, you can see that -x grants executable rights to Files, and ACCESS rights to directories.

Comment: I'm confused. Is it possible to mount a tmp directory without it being a partition of its own?

Comment: @TomKlino Yes, and this is more or less the purpose of the `tmpfs` filesystem, some [doc here](https://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs). If you want permanent storage, you can create a block file and mount it as any directory too (loopback mount), a [blog post](https://samindaw.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/mounting-a-file-as-a-file-system-in-linux/) on this. (Links are for illustration, dig the subject if you want to got any of this way)

Answer (score 2):

Removing execution bit recursively in `/tmp` with `chmod -R -x /tmp` does not prevent file execution from `/tmp`.

First, it only applies to the files **currently** in `/tmp`. New files created after you run `chmod` will have no restrictions in them.

Second, if you remove the execution bit from another user's file it doesn't prevent the user from executing it. The user can add the execution bit back after you change it.

Third, the execution bit in directories is actually called "search" and has a different meaning than for files. Given this directory structure:

```
.:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 ago 25 13:54 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 ago 25 13:54 dir2
./dir1:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 ago 25 13:54 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 ago 25 13:54 file2

./dir2:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 ago 25 13:54 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 ago 25 13:54 file2
```

If you remove "search" bit from dir1 with `chmod -x dir1` you get this:

```
$ chmod -x dir1
$ ls -l dir1
ls: no se puede acceder a 'dir1/file2': Permiso denegado
ls: no se puede acceder a 'dir1/file1': Permiso denegado
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file1
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file2

$ cat dir1/file1 
cat: dir1/file1: Permiso denegado
```

If you do this on /tmp you'll get an unusable temp dir, and several programs will crash on you.

So the `noexec` mount option can't be replaced by chmodding.

If you really want to do it without adding a new partition<sup>**1**</sup> or using a tmpfs/loop-mounted file (as suggested by Shane), the you can try the bind-fu in [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/a/359544/180829)

<sub>**1**: I'd also argue you wouldn't have this problem if you were using logical volumes ;)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Some files, also in temp, do actually need to be executable without the need to run. Marking the partition with `noexec` will still allow you to set the `+x`, but execution (by shell, ld-linux-x86-64.so) is prohibited. This leads to an additional layer of security as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of several ways, but felt using `setfacl` (ACL) would work best. Apache runs as nobody, and to execute a shell script in temp you need bash.

`setfacl -m u:nobody:r bash`

Apache can still read and write in `/tmp` but not execute.